# How to add series number value on my sql columns

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table and I need to put a series number(without duplicate) on each value of the columns.

I do it manually by editing each columns using this,|

```
UPDATE mytable where column = '123'
SET  table_column1 = '955';
```

then next

```
UPDATE mytable where column = '124'
SET    table_column2 = '956';
```

but this one takes time for me.

There's any solution or fastest way to do this??

I'm thinking of I will add another auto increment but 2 increment is advisable ?

Here's the screenshot of my data below[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add another auto-increment. But you can do it with one query if you don't care about a specific order

```
UPDATE mytable 
cross join (select @rank := 0) r
SET    table_column2 = 956 + (@rank := @rank + 1)
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09e1af/1)

If you need a specific order then you can define the `@rank` variable outside the query and add an `order by`

```
set @rank := 0;

UPDATE mytable  
SET    table_column2 = 956 + (@rank := @rank + 1)
order by id
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a34732/1)